# Elasticserach - Override mapping definitions during aggregation query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an aggregation query -

```
POST /my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    ...
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "venueId.keyword": [
              "ID1",
              "ID2"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "venue": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "venueId.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "multi_agg": {
          "terms": {
                "field": "networkName.keyword"
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In case I have 2 networks (for same venue) with the names `XXX` and `xxx`. The aggregation output count 2 networks and only 1 name - `xxx`, for example -

```
 "aggregations": {
    "venue": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "ID1",
          "doc_count": 5,
          "multi_agg": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "xxx",
                "doc_count": 2
              }...
```

The reason for the above is a mapping which defined as lowercase -

```
GET /my-index/_mapping/field/networkName.keyword
{
  "my-index": {
    "mappings": {
      "_doc": {
        "networkName.keyword": {
          "full_name": "networkName.keyword",
          "mapping": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "normalizer": "lowercase"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Due to backward compatibility, updating the settings is not possible. Please advise if it is possible and how to override the mapping during the aggregation query in order to get in output 2 different keys with count 1 and names `XXX` and `xxx`.

Answer (score 1):

Once the mapping is created it cant be overridden,
You can create a new index with the mapping of your old index, Just make sure while adding the mapping for your new index to update your respective field with the correct data type

Rest is simple just run this code once your new index is created with the required mapping

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "old_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_index" 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

WE have found a way to return the actual with no schema changes or re indexing. Just by changing the agg part of the query -

```
"aggs":{
      "venue":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"venueId.keyword"
         },
         "aggregations":{
            "top_client_hits":{
               "top_hits":{
                  "version":false,
                  "explain":false,
                  "_source":{
                     "includes":[
                        "networkId",
                        "networkName"
                     ],
                     "excludes":[
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```